# Returning string lines that only contain listbox items

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve lines of data from a text file that contain items I added to a listbox, but it just keeps returning all lines of data from my test file:

```
foreach (var item in searchValList.Items)
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(searchValList.Text))
        {
           sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
           resultsTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
           resultsTextBox.Text = "The value was not found in this file";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems in your code.

1. `searchValList.Text` has to be `item.ToString();`
2. Inner while loop spins till `EOF` for fisrt iteration, in second Iteration it will always return null since `EOF` already reached.
3. In all the else part inside the loop you're setting "The value was not found in this file"
   that is completely wrong

It should be something like this.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("...");
var listboxItems = searchValList.Cast<object>().Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToList();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (listboxItems.Any(x=> line.Contains(x)))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }     
}

if(sb.Length > 0)
{
    resultsTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
}
else
{
     resultsTextBox.Text = "The value was not found in this file";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: My Apologies.  I am new to this site.

Comment: @user2836200 no problem, this should work perfectly, if not then feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for the same value in all the lines, (and virtually your outer loop is meaningless)

Change following

```
 if (line.Contains(searchValList.Text))
```

to

```
 if (item.Text != null && line.Contains(item.Text.ToString()))
```

Comment: `item.Text` is not going to work. It should be item.ToString()

Comment: Not only that, Look at my answer to see number of mistakes in this question

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this way since you have a listbox. Try this :

```
foreach (var item in searchValList.Items)
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(item.ToString()))
        {
           sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
           resultsTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
           resultsTextBox.Text = "The value was not found in this file";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working now with some of the values I try, but not all.  Any idea on what could be causing that?

Comment: may be the file is missing the data, or you do not have all the item in the listbox.

Comment: For testing purposes I am just copy / pasting from the testfile to add an item to the listbox.  Still playing with to try and figure it out.